# Is there a list of my questions that can now have a bounty started?

Tags: feature-request, questions, bounties, network-profile

Is there a URL in the main stackexchange.com site that will allow to see the list of my questions in the different sites that haven't got an accepted answer and that have been asked long enough that can now have a bounty started?

As far as I can see, there is a URL where I can see my most recent questions, but I can't see any indication anywhere about the bounty status for each of them.

Comment: Even in a world with unlimited time and budget, I fail to see the need for it. How come you don't know which questions you still have?

Comment: if a question has the value to start a bounty on it, you will still remember it and have no use of such a function!

Answer (score 4):

If you've asked so many questions that you can't remember which they were or whether you've received useful answers, then there's a serious problem above and beyond your inability to offer bounties for those questions.

The list of your most recent questions is precisely what you want. Combine that with [a little bit of knowledge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) about the conditions under which you can offer a bounty, and you're all set.

Answer (score 2):

You will start bounty if you really want to have solution of that question with some advertisement cost. i.e. You really want solution to that question and waiting for bounty period to start.

If I am not wrong, you can start bounty to any 2 days old question. No additional requirement to list that questions.